# Can we have a foam like texture in a bottle in Render Engine : Eevee?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm stuck in a project , I've to make a foam like texture in a bottle but having difficulty to make that in Eevee , in cycles it could be achieved but the system heats up a lot so no video rendering possible .
Anyone have any ideas how to do that in Eevee ?

This is what I want to achieve
[image]
this is the node structure I tried on my own which only works in cycles but not Eevee
[image]

Foam in cycles render
[image]

Comment: May I ask in what way creating a foam-like texture should be related to *Geometry Nodes*? Did you mean *Shader Nodes* instead of *Geometry Nodes*?

Comment: I have only tried this in shader editor but if someone has a different approach via geometry nodes , it will help too .

Comment: To be honest, I see little chance of achieving a convincing result with *Geometry Nodes* without exorbitant effort. You should rather concentrate on the shader for this task, that's my advice.

Comment: okay , let me remove the tag then also can you suggest an approach in shader ?

Comment: @Crantisz may have an idea, he would be one of the shader experts here on BSE.